# Resque - Check if stopped/started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, jobs, resque

I'm using `resque` to schedule some jobs in my application and I need to know if there is a way to detect whether resque is started or stopped?

To start resque I usually do:

```
rake resque:start
```

and to stop it:

```
rake resque:stop
```

Is there any utility (i.e. `Resque.started?`) that returns true if resque is started and false otherwise?

Comment: `Resque.workers.all?(&:working?)` to check if all workers are up and running. `Resque.workers.any?(&:working?)`, if anyone of the worker is up.

Comment: @kiddorails it's returning `false` all the time. Maybe I'll use this: `ps aux | grep resque` and check its output. If only 1 row it means that resque is stopped, otherwise (> 1 row) resque is started.

Comment: Answer depends on point where you want to know if Resque started or not. Resque, Sidekiq etc are designed by PubSub pattern with Redis as pipeline. _Publisher_ part is in your Rails app, when _Subscriber_ one is run separately. Moreover, _Subscriber_ may be run as many instances and on another server. So, _in general_, you have no ability (from the scratch) to check if _Subscriber_ run or not

Comment: I think you have to describe your goal deeply in the question.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I have some background jobs in my application and I use Resque to schedule those jobs (_resque_schedule.yml_). I want to detect if Resque is started or not in a bash script. The bash script will run through crontab. From the bash script I want to start `Resque` if it has stopped.

Comment: Oh, you have to start from the problem description definitely :) The good way is to use system tools like Upstart, SystemD etc for auto start/restart services(nginx, puma, redis, resque) and not the cron+bash scripts.